# Shrinking horizontal list

Tags: html, css

I need to create an effect using css similar to the main navigation menu on apple.com.

I will have a list on the left and a search box on the right - when clicking in the search box, the list will shrink while the text box expands.

The different with my list is that the items will be left aligned and not centered + there should be an even amount of margin/padding to the right of each.

Apple are using a table style layout which wont work for this.

Any other ideas on how to achieve this?

Here is where i am up to: http://jsfiddle.net/h8gCd/6/

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Link 1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Link 2</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Link 3</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Link 4</span></a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>Link 5</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <form>
        <input type="text" />
    </form>
</div>


div {
    width: 100%;
    background: #e1e1e1;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 820px;
}

ul {
    float: left;
    width: 600px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: red;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000
}
a:hover {
    color: #444
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 77px;
}

li.last {
    margin-right: 0;
}

form {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    background: green;
}

input {
    width: 194px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

input:focus {
    width: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Apple website is using `display: table` and `display: table-cell` to achieve this effect:

http://jsfiddle.net/h8gCd/7/

```
div {
    width: 100%;
    background: #e1e1e1;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 820px;
}
ul {
    display: table;
    width: 600px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: red;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000
}
a:hover {
    color: #444
}
li {
    display: table-cell;
    margin-right: 77px;
    width: 20%;
}
li.last {
    margin-right: 0;
}
form {
    background: green;
}
input {
    width: 194px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
input:focus {
    width: 250px;
}

<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Link 1</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Link 2</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Link 3</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Link 4</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>Link 5</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <form>
                <input type="text" />
            </form>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```